# In a ControlTemplate, I want to apply the same style to all TextBlocks

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a class library, in which I've created default styles for TextBlock, which is applied to every TextBlock in any application that uses this class library.

The problem is that I sometimes need to exclude TextBlocks inside some other controls (say, ribbon, or my own Custom Control). The textblocks are not accessible, for instance the ones inside a tab item heade.

Is there any ways to force wpf to use another style for all TextBlocks inside one control?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is a simple solution, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057639/wpf-subcontrol-like-textblock-doesnt-inherit-style-from-window-with-templates/27060189#27060189 (looking in the non-accepted answer of Mike Strobe).

Comment: Thank you @KingKing, the link was great. interesting that Mike's answer is from yesterday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. As it turns out, this is not possible, see [Mike Strobel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27065140/742775)'s answer for an explanation of the reason and the rational behind it.

The workaround is to not create an implicit style for `TextBlock`, because it will affect `TextBlock`s inside other `ControlTemplate`s.

What works for me is to derive a class from `TextBlock`, say `Label` and apply my style to it, and then use it wherever I want a `TextBlock` with that specific style.

A more "Wpf Natural" way to deal with that is to create a style with a key.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add an empty (or any other) style to the resource dictionary of any ancestor of the `TextBlock` nested inside the control referencing the resource dictionary, in which the global style is defined. For instance, the global style defined for `TextBlock` won't be applied in this case (if the resource dictionary is referenced by an ancestor of the `Button` control):

```
<Button>
    <Button.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock"/>
    </Button.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="FooBar"/>
<Button>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very much expected, but in practice it does not work.

Comment: Well it does work with a simple project created solely for the purpose of testing this solution, so the fault must be something specific to your code. Could you please provide code that would shed some light on the problem? For starters, how do you define the default style and how do you force all `TextBlock`s in an application to use that style?

Comment: In my class library, in Themes folder I have a ResourceDictionary file named TextBlockStyles with `<Style TargetType="TextBlock">`...
This is Merged in Generic.xaml.
In my application, the generic.xaml from class library is merged, so all of its styles are applied to all respective controls in the application.

Comment: I've recreated the project structure you described and provided example still works as expected. Try creating new WpfApplication project, add reference to the library and resource dictionary in question, put the code above inside the main window and see if the style is applied to the `TextBlock`. If it is, then the fault must be somewhere in your control library. Otherwise it's somewhere in the "consumer" project. On the other hand - is the `TextBlock` you don't want to apply the style to nested somewhere inside one of your controls or rather in the "consumer" project?

Comment: I also recreated test projects from scratch and got mixed results. I can only change the appearance of bare `TextBlock`s and TextBlocks inside my own `CustomControls`. For instance whatever I do, the Button gets the unwanted style. More information on the reason in given in [Mike Strobel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057639/wpf-subcontrol-like-textblock-doesnt-inherit-style-from-window-with-templates/27060189#27060189).
Thank you very much