# WPF Style at Windows or App level yields different results

Tags: c#, wpf, styling

I'm trying to learn Styling in WPF and encountered a funny thing:

There is a difference when I apply a style at application or (main) window level.

When I define the following resource in the **App.xaml**:

```
<Application.Resource>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    </Style>
<Application.Resource>
```

the GroupBox caption is bold *and* italic.

When I instead define the styling in the **MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

The GroupBox caption box is only bold and *not* italic.

Can anybody explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In picking TextBlock you have unearthed something.  TextBlock is not derived from Control, and thus behaves slightly differently.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27065140/4258144 :

> there is a curious rule in WPF implicit styles are only inherited
>   across template boundaries by elements which inherit from the Control
>   class

I guess you can add to that, "unless it is globally specified in App.xaml".

*UPDATE:*

Following comments, here's a look at a GroupBox visual tree, taken from Snoop.

[image]

Comment: Interesting, but are you sure that is the case here? The TextBlock items are styled in both cases, but only when the Styles are defined in the App.xaml both adaptions are applied to the GroupBox caption (which is a TextBlock, I guess).

Comment: Yeah, if you put text in the header, a TextBlock will get created in the visual tree.  You can prove this with Snoop (or VS2015 visual tree explorer thingy).

Comment: I', not convincent that this is the answer. The styling of the TextBlock is also applied when defined in the Window, only the TextBlock in the GroupBox is not influenced then.

Comment: Well that's true.  If you add a TextBlock directly in the Window the style is applied.  Because it is not going across a template boundary. Consider this scenario, the italic is not applied inside controls with their own templates:

<Window.Resources>
    . . . styles ...
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>Applied</TextBlock>
        <Button>Not Applied</Button>
        <GroupBox Header="Group Header">
            <Button>Hello World</Button>
        </GroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>